# What is the reward for reaching the highest rank?

Tags: elite-beat-agents

I've already unlocked all three bonus songs. What is the reward for reaching the rank above Five Star Commander (and what is that rank called)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The highest rank is **Lovin' Machine**.  You need 80 million points to attain it and when you do, you get a [special congratulations picture.](http://youtu.be/c5Y_jUyeUGU?t=37s)